# Break a single list into 2 lists using Python

Tags: python

I have a list

```
['2', '16SCSE102014', '15/03/2019', '16SCSE101350', '15/03/2019', '1', '16SCSE102020', '02/02/2020']
```

which I want to break into 2 lists as

```
['16SCSE102014','16SCSE101350','16SCSE102020'] 

['15/03/2019','15/03/2019','02/02/2020']
```

The number in the `'2'` and `'1'` are markers that tells number of pairs `('16SCSE102020','Date')` that will follow.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a pretty straight forward solution would be to iterate over the list, ignoring the markers ('1', '2' etc) since they seem to have no real use, and inserting to you resulting lists in order (if your input is indeed ordered as seen in your example, otherwise a simple regex could do, inform me if you need it)
so the code would be:

```
strings, dates = [], []
i = 0
while i <len(input_list):
    if not input_list[i].isdigit(): 
        strings.append(input_list[i])
        i += 1
        dates.append(input_list[i])
    i += 1
```

so the code assumes your strings cannot be interperted as digits (reserved for the markers) and that the input is ordered the way you've shown it to be

Comment: This code does not work. On some iteration it will append `i+1` item to dates, on next iteration it will append the same item to strings.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderDmitriev, it's fixed now. that's the result of writing code in the web browser without checking it

Comment: And t still doesn't work. Python range-loops are different from C for loops as you can't modify the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you might use external libraries, [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) has function [split_at](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_at) well suited to your task:

```
import more_itertools
lst = ['2', '16SCSE102014', '15/03/2019', '16SCSE101350', '15/03/2019', '1', '16SCSE102020', '02/02/2020']
splitted = list(more_itertools.split_at(lst, lambda x:x in ('1','2')))
print(splitted)
```

Output:

```
[[], ['16SCSE102014', '15/03/2019', '16SCSE101350', '15/03/2019'], ['16SCSE102020', '02/02/2020']]
```

Note that due to `'2'` being first element of `lst` first element of `splitted` is empty `list`, due to this list interesting you are `splitted[1]` and `splitted[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate the list in a trivial way. This might not be the most Pythonic or efficient way, but you didn't specify any requirements, so it might as well be the best approach for your use case.

```py
data = ['2', '16SCSE102014', '15/03/2019', '16SCSE101350', '15/03/2019', '1', '16SCSE102020', '02/02/2020']

list1 = []
list2 = []

x = 0
while x < len(data):
    count = int(data[x])
    x += 1
    for i in range(count):
        list1.append(data[x])
        x += 1
        list2.append(data[x])
        x += 1
```

Afterwards, `list1` and `list2` are equal to the two lists mentioned in your question.

NB: If the original list is not needed anymore, you could use `list.pop()` which simplifies the code a bit:

```py
data = ['2', '16SCSE102014', '15/03/2019', '16SCSE101350', '15/03/2019', '1', '16SCSE102020', '02/02/2020']

list1 = []
list2 = []

while data:
    count = int(data.pop(0))
    for i in range(count):
        list1.append(data.pop(0))
        list2.append(data.pop(0))
```